# Does AWS Textract support scanning driving licenses and passports?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr

I'd like to use AWS Textract to extract text from UK driving licenses and UK passport scans. Is this possible because the tests I've performed using the Textract demo all fail.

Answer (score 0):

This works if you follow the requirements as specified in the **AWS Management consol**e at this URL:

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/textract/home?region=us-east-1#/demo

Upload, for example a PNG of you document. Documents must be fewer than 11 pages, smaller than 5 MB, and one of the following formats: JPEG, PNG, or PDF.